How should I pass the apiRequest "attachment" parameter for a FedEx Image upload
*** Updated:
I'm using the FedEx REST API for image upload (/documents/v1/lhsimages/upload), and I'm getting back an error:
    [errors] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 1001
            [message] => Invalid request: invalid input : Invalid document details
        )


I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm passing the data up - typically in a cURL request for the FedEx API you would do
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->apiRequest);

where $this->apiRequest is a json encoded request body.  This works for other API requests.  But the Upload Image is a bit tricky because it contains field data plus a file:
document: {"document": {"referenceId": "1234", "name": "LH2.PNG",    "contentType": "image/png",    "meta": { "imageType": "SIGNATURE","imageIndex": "IMAGE_1"}},"rules": {"workflowName": "LetterheadSignature" }}
attachment: file.PNG

What I was passing was
        $body = (object)[
            'referenceId' => 'Signature',
            'name' => $filename,
            'contentType' => $filetype,
            'rules' => (object)[
               'workflowName' => 'LetterheadSignature',
            ],
            'meta' => (object)[
               'imageType' => 'SIGNATURE',
               'imageIndex' => 'IMAGE_1',
            ]
        ];

         $sent_data = [
            'document' => json_encode($body),
            'attachment' => $file,
         ];

         $this->apiRequest = $sent_data;

I tried building $file parameter two ways:
      $handle = fopen($full_filename, "r");
      $file_contents = fread($handle, filesize($full_filename));
      fclose($handle);
      $file = base64_encode($file_contents);

and also:
      $file = curl_file_create($full_filename, $filetype, $filename);


where
      $filename = 'image-of-signature.png';
      $filetype = 'image/png';
      $full_filename = 'path-to-file' . $filename;

Neither worked; both gave me the Invalid request: invalid input : Invalid document details 1001 error.
The FedEx documentation describes the attachment parameter as:
string <file>
Input the actual document/file to be uploaded.

I have also tried passing the actual path to the file, and of course that doesn't work either.

You'r encoding your whole request as JSON there - but only the content of document needs to be JSON. And how you are creating your $file parameter, is also wrong. This is supposed to be a normal HTTP file upload - so use the CURLFile class for that.

Yes, JSON for the document parameter, and the CURLFile instance for file.

Maybe you do indeed need to send the actual file content in string form, the documentation lists string <file> as the parameter type. Not sure why they'd insist on it being a multipart/form-data request then though, if no actual HTTP file upload is performed

You were right - the document should have been a CURLFile.  My issue was in the structure of the sent message.  The documentation had  a bug that sent me astray.

Contrary to what is shown in the FedEx API documentation, the document element and the rules element are at the same level.  The correct structure for the body is
      $body = (object)[
         'document' => (object)[
            'referenceId' => 'Letterhead',
            'name' => $filename,
            'contentType' => $filetype,
            'meta' => (object)[
               'imageType' => 'LETTERHEAD',
               'imageIndex' => 'IMAGE_2',
            ],
         ],
         'rules' => (object)[
            'workflowName' => 'LetterheadSignature',
         ]
      ];


As discovered by @Emtek, the real issue is that the FedEx API documentation is wrong.


The document element and the rules element are at the same level.
document is both the array index in the POST data and the name of the json_encoded portion of the data.  The correct structure for the body is

      $body = (object)[
         'document' => (object)[
            'referenceId' => 'Letterhead',
            'name' => $filename,
            'contentType' => $filetype,
            'meta' => (object)[
               'imageType' => 'LETTERHEAD',
               'imageIndex' => 'IMAGE_2',
            ],
         ],
         'rules' => (object)[
            'workflowName' => 'LetterheadSignature',
         ]
      ];

Then you do
         $sent_data = [
            'document' => json_encode($body),
            'attachment' => $file,
         ];

         $this->apiRequest = $sent_data;

If you don't do all these things, you will get the 1001 error:
        "message": "Invalid request: invalid input : Invalid document details"

or
        "message": "Invalid request: invalid input : WorkFlow Name"

The original person to point out that the position of rules was incorrect in the documentation was @Emtek in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78697033

The appropriate open-api-json
{
  "requestBody": {
    "content": {
      "multipart/form-data": {
        "schema": {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/FullSchema-ImageUploadServiceInputVO"},
        "examples": {
          "Full-Schema": {"value": "document: {\"document\": {\"referenceId\": \"1234\", \"name\": \"LH2.PNG\",    \"contentType\": \"image/png\",    \"meta\": { \"imageType\": \"SIGNATURE\",\"imageIndex\": \"IMAGE_1\"}},\"rules\": {\"workflowName\": \"LetterheadSignature\" }}\nattachment: file.PNG"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

So maybe add this curl option:
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
  )

//And build the atttament like this:
$sent_data = [
            'document' => json_encode($body),
            'attachment' => new CURLFILE($full_filename)
         ];


Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately, I still get "Invalid document details."
